# OR-based search using jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Imagine the following basic table (the [search] is from applying the filter widget):

```js
Name            Address
------------------------------------
[search]        [search]
------------------------------------
Albert          St. Albert Street 2
Mona            St. Albert Street 13
```

What I've done is that I've hidden the [search] row and placed a single input search field above my table. Then I use the following code to apply the search:

```js
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    $('table').find('input.tablesorter-filter').val(search);
    $('table').trigger('search', false);
});
```

However, this searches the table using an AND-based behvaiour, i.e. all columns in a row must match the search in order to be a successfull match. What I'd like instead is that if any of the colums match, then the row is a successfull match (i.e. OR-based behaviour).

Typing `Albert` in the searchbox should return both rows, not just the first one.

So, is this possible using tablesorter?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you may need to extend it because there's no way of doing it with the options/methods that are available by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with tablesorter v2.10.8 :/

I did solve the problem however, if anyone is interested...

```js
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('table').each(function() { // Search among possibly multiple tables

        // Hide all table rows
        $(this).find('tbody tr').hide();

        // Search through all td:s and if a match is found => display the tr that the td belongs to
        $(this).find('tbody td').filter(function() {
             return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1; // case insensitive search
        }).parent().show();

        $(this).trigger('applyWidgets'); // for zebra
    });
});
```